# For what use is the package-lock.json if it changes everytime you run npm install?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

If everytime you run npm install, npm looks up your package.json rather than your package-lock.json, what is it used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses both to determine which versions to install. The `package-lock.json` file indicates the versions installed during the previous run so that you should get exactly the same versions when you pull the code and run `npm install`.

Prior to having a `.lock` file you'd get approximately the same version, but subtle differences could break deployments in a spectacular way.

The purpose of the lock file is to have reproducible builds.

You can always remove the lock and reinstall, but you may get slightly different versions of the dependencies. This is made obvious if you use a version control tool and look at the changes made.